# Why would the Better Wordpress Minify plugin cause alignment issues when activated?

Tags: html, wordpress, css, javascript, plugin

I just installed the Better Wordpress Minify plugin to speed up a Wordpress site. The plugin is causing a couple very small alignment issues, but I can't seem to get the plugin settings adjusted to avoid these errors.

I even went through and disabled all of the CSS/HTML/JS settings, but the errors remained. The only thing that works is deactivating the plugin altogether.

Comment: What is the name of the plugin that you're using? And what is your WordPress version.
Sometimes plugins are just incompatible with the WordPress version you're using, or it conflicts with other plugins installed.

Comment: Try deactivating all plugins except minify, that way you can have sure about your problem

Comment: Specifically, what change is being made to the source that is causing the "alignment issues"? Are the pages valid HTML/CSS?

Comment: The plugin is Wordpress 4.1 and the plugin is Better Wordpress Minify. I know the problem is with the minify plugin, because when I deactivate it, the problem is fixed. The pages are valid HTML/CSS. I am not sure what causes the issue with this specific plugin.

Comment: First, I wonder if the Stack Exchange WordPress forum will attract more attention to this issue. Second, it is not true that you can be sure that Better Wordpress Minify is the cause of the problem and not some other plugin unless you follow Isleno Ituriel's advice and disable all other plugins. WP enqueing and then rendering a page are obscenely complex and relocating CSS and JS can dramatically change things. I personally gave up trying to use Better WordPress Minify because it always broke something on my site. w3d's suggestion is also excellent: after rendering, what code is different?

Answer (score 2):

The alignment issues is caused by white-space removal. This would cause small alignment issues in most browsers because a carriage return will fill in a non-block elements. If one were to remove the carriage return from a span it would condense. If you add a carriage return it will expand. 
Without seeing code one can only speculate.